# How to create a "Facebook friends list" from a local file containing Facebook friends ids?

Tags: facebook, facebook-integration, friend-list

I have a local text file containing Facebook ids, one per line, like this:

```
938751234570943
9875123457623
...
43639193242324
```

These ids actually are those of my Facebook friends interested in jazz.

Now I would like to create a "jazz" Facebook friends list ("[Facebook friends lists](http://cloudhighclub.com/smart-use-of-facebook-friends-list-circle-friends-like-google-plus/)" are Facebook feature) to easily invite them to jazz events.

How to create this Facebook friends list?

Comment: You might want to approach it in another way...with ids, the only way that will work is an API method. Are you looking to quickly move friends to lists?

Comment: My (non-facebook) address book has for each person: an optional facebook id, and a list of tags. The tags are more up-to-date that anything in my facebook. So I want to regularly create facebook friends lists based on those tags. When inviting people to a facebook event, this will allow me to more easily invite all people that have a certain tag. Maybe there is an application that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a bash script to compare Facebook and my address book.

Before running this script, I go to my Facebook friends list "jazz", and copy the generated HTML source into `jazz.html`.

When I run the script, it shows which jazz-tagged contacts are missing from Facebook, and I proceed to add them manually.

The `jazz-addressbook` line depends on your particular address book format, so please adapt it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a text file containing the Facebook ids of all the people in my Facebook friends list "jazz"
cat jazz.html | sed -e "s/li class/\n/g" | grep "checkableListItem selectedCheckable" | sed -e "s/.*value=\"//g" | sed -e "s/\".*//g" | grep -v "Done" | sort > jazz-facebook

# Create a text file containing the Facebook ids of all the people marked "jazz" in my address book
cat address-book.xml | depends on your address book format | sort > jazz-addressbook

echo "Missing from Facebook:"
diff jazz-facebook jazz-addressbook | grep ">" | sed -e "s/> //g"

echo "Missing from address book:"
diff jazz-facebook jazz-addressbook | grep "<" | sed -e "s/< //g"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook API to get the information you want and then add them to a database (or your definition of list).

In order to use that data, you need to query Facebook and although I'm not 100% sure, in order to do it, (even public data) you will need authorization from the user.

Comment: I should have been clearer: "friends list" are a Facebook thing, you can see them after clicking "Edit friends". I don't want to export anything FROM facebook, I want to import the list TO facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API would probably be the most natural. However, if you have access to Linux you can at least extract the friends' names using `wget` as follows (see also [wget for fetching Facebook profile/friend pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821696/wget-for-fetching-facebook-profile-friend-pages)):

```
wget -U Mozilla --wait 1 "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=938751234570943"
```

This will download the publicly available content and depending on privacy settings the name of the contact will appear and could be parsed.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough, let me put it in other words: I already have the ids as local data. I need to push them back to Facebook in a way that Facebook will create what it calls a "friends list".